# AS3 Make object visible/invisible depending on position of another object

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, tween

I'm building a website with a gallery that slides from left to right using AS3 tweening, stopping at specific x coordinates to show a specific item.

When a coordinate is reached, I want to make information about the item visible.

I have this written and I don't understand why it isn't working. When I preview, the Info1 movieclip doesn't appear.

```
if (GalleryPanel.x==4715.45)
{
    Info1.visible=true;
}
else
{
    Info1.visible=false;
}
```

This is the code that  moves the gallery:

```
var tweenitem1:Tween = new Tween(GalleryPanel, "x", Strong.easeOut, GalleryPanel.x, 4715.45, 1, true);
```

For now, Info 1 is just a moviclip I placed on the timeline to test my code.  The Info 1 symbol properties were set to invisible; when it is set to visible, it stays visible when GalleryPanel is translated.

Comment: You need to show the code that sets the X value.

Comment: As well as the code that creates info1. Simply setting somethings visible value to true does not add that thing to the display list. And you may think you are outing somethings X value at the intended spot but may be making a mistake there. So just hit edit under your post and add that code for those two things

Comment: var tweenitem1:Tween = new Tween(GalleryPanel, "x", Strong.easeOut, GalleryPanel.x, 4715.45, 1, true); 

For now, Info 1 is just a moviclip I placed on the timeline to test my code

Comment: Don't post code in a comment. Edit your original post. There is an edit button near the bottom of your post. Click that and then post this code. Thanks

Comment: @user7083681 did you get the right answer for your previous question?

Comment: Also make sure to include the code in which you create info1

Comment: So why isn't info1 visible? You gotta post more code :)

Comment: because I set it to not be visible in the properties panel. when it's set to visible it is visible but it stays visible regardless of where GalleryPanel is

Comment: Thanks. I think using floating posing Numbers to check equality is unstable. Can you trace the X value to see if it's actually what you think it is?

Comment: I could if I wasn't completely incompetent haha. I've only been using flash for like 2 weeks.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
if (GalleryPanel.x > 4715 && GalleryPanel.x < 4716)
{
    Info1.visible=true;
}
```

Using decimal places to check equality is dicey.

Comment: I thought it might be something to do with the decimals, because how do you move something by less than 1 pixel? I didn't know the && bit though but I'll use that in my code. It's still not working for me though, Info 1 stays in whatever visibility state it was set to initially.

Comment: @user7083681 to clarify, you can have an object at a fraction of a pixel. It's just that sometimes there are rounding inaccuracies in flash. Like instead of putting it at 143.2 it might go to 143.2000000009. That seems to be more an issue with calculations though. But I thought it was worth a try. I can't guess any more what the problem is but if you post the rest of your code I'm sure someone can figure it out.

Comment: Your if block isn't being executed. If it were, the else part would at least be getting called which would set your visible info1 to false. That's the problem. But why it isn't getting executed will have to do with where you pith at if block and what is around it. Again. More code is needed. Is that if block inside a timer event handler or an enterFrame event handler? Cause it needs to be. (Or inside a function that gets called in an event handler like timer or enterFrame.)

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't work because it is executed once (and only once) at the beginning. It doesn't continuously monitor the variable.

But doing that would be a bad idea anyway. You'd have to continuously waste resources to check this variable (and if you want to add more destinations it gets even worse).

> When a coordinate is reached, I want to make information about the item visible.

The coordinate is reached when the tween finishes. To recognise that, just add a listener for the [`TweenEvent.MOTION_FINISH`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/transitions/Tween.html#event:motionFinish). something like

```
import fl.transitions.TweenEvent;
import fl.transitions.Tween;
import fl.transitions.easing.*;

var tweenitem1:Tween = new Tween(GalleryPanel, "x", Strong.easeOut, GalleryPanel.x, 4715.45, 1, true);

tweenitem1.addEventListener(TweenEvent.MOTION_FINISH, onMotionFinish);

function onMotionFinish(te:TweenEvent):void
{
    Info1.visible = true;
}
```

When the next tween starts, to transition to a different state of your application, you should hide `Info1` again.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was doing in the first place, showing the info when the tween happens. The reason I decided to change it is because I want to add swipe gesture inputs to tween the GalleryPanel to the next item. I don't know how I would make the right info appear without knowing which item is currently showing.

Comment: @user7083681 it doesn't matter what initiates the Tween. The solution I posted still applies.  "*I don't know how I would make the right info appear without knowing which item is currently showing.*" You should keep track of the currently displayed item in a variable.

Comment: Well, anyway, I've just put each gallery item on its own page and I tween them in separately. Works 100% better.